# OWL API NoSuchMethodError

Tags: owl-api

I am using logmap that uses OWL API 4.1.3 and getting the following error when compiling:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyID.getOntologyIRI()Lcom/google/common/base/Optional;
    at uk.ac.ox.krr.logmap2.OntologyLoader.setOWLOntology(OntologyLoader.java:150)
    at uk.ac.ox.krr.logmap2.OntologyLoader.<init>(OntologyLoader.java:113)
    at uk.ac.ox.krr.logmap2.overlapping.LexicalOverlappingExtractor.createOverlapping(LexicalOverlappingExtractor.java:156)
    at uk.ac.ox.krr.logmap2.overlapping.LexicalOverlappingExtractor.createOverlapping(LexicalOverlappingExtractor.java:131)
    at uk.ac.ox.krr.logmap2.LogMap2Core.OverlappingEstimation(LogMap2Core.java:873)
    at uk.ac.ox.krr.logmap2.LogMap2Core.<init>(LogMap2Core.java:293)
    at uk.ac.ox.krr.logmap2.LogMap2Core.<init>(LogMap2Core.java:240)
    at uk.ac.ox.krr.logmap2.LogMap2_Matcher.<init>(LogMap2_Matcher.java:145)
    at Alignment.LogMap.LogMapAligner.getAlignment(LogMapAligner.java:40)
    at Main.main(Main.java:50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple OWLAPI versions on your classpath. Make sure there is only one, and that is a version compatible with all the libraries you're using.

Comment: What if the different libraries obligatorily have to depend on different specific version of the OWL API, how can we manage this ?

Comment: That's a problem, there's no easy fix for that. If you have a lost of the libraries and they're open source I can try creating pull requests to update them to the latest owlapi release; otherwise the only other fix I can think of is to run them on separate VMs. OSGI might help but I'm no expert.

Comment: But if ever you can make both LogMap [2] and AML [1] use the latests version of OWL API, it can greatly help, thanks
1. https://github.com/AgreementMakerLight
2. https://github.com/ernestojimenezruiz/logmap-matcher

Comment: I have rebuit both AML and LogMap using the OWL API v4.1.3. I am still getting the same error

Comment: What's OntologyLoader.java line 150?

Comment: this.owl2DLProfileReport = this.profileChecker.getReport4OWL2DL();

Comment: Pretty weird, no call to OWLOntology::getOntologyIRI?

Comment: I have pushed everything on Github, RDFInjectionAndAlignment[1] is the main projet, it is using LogMap[2] and AML[3] that both uses OWL API.

1. https://github.com/noorbakerally/RDFInjectionAndAlignment
2. https://github.com/noorbakerally/logmap-matcher
3. https://github.com/noorbakerally/AML-Project

Comment: If you run the main in RDFInjectionAndAlignment, you will the error